# Let $I_n = \int_0^1 x^ne^{-x} dx$, show that $0 < I_n < \frac{1}{n+1}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, euler-mascheroni-constant

The question ask us to use the fact that if $f(x) < g(x)$, $\forall x \in [a,b]$, then $\int_a^b f(x) dx < \int_a^b g(x) dx $.

I have no idea about how to choose $f(x)$ so that $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ will smaller than $\int_0^1 x^ne^{-x} dx$ (which is $I_n$) and $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ will be $0$.

I have tried letting $f(x) = 0$ but it seems not working.

And I also don't know how to choose $g(x)$. I have tried to let $g(x) = \frac{-1}{(n+1)^2}$(becaues its integral will be $\frac{1}{n+1}$, but I don't know how to compare $\frac{-1}{(n+1)^2}$ with $ x^ne^{-x}$

Thanks for giving any tips in advance!

Comment: You can compare the integrand with $x^n$ and use that as your $g(x)$. 
Here $f(x) = x^n e^{-x}$

Comment: note that $\int_0^1 x^n dx = \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{x}>1$ for $x\in(0,1]$ and hence $e^{-x}<1$ for all such $x$, now $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}e^{-x}dx<\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}dx=\dfrac{1}{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a little better.

By the integral Chebychev inequality
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Integral_Chebyshev_inequality),
since $x^n$ and $e^{-x}$
are monotonic in different directions,

$\int_0^1 x^ne^{-x} dx
\le \int_0^1 x^n dx\int_0^1e^{-x} dx
=\dfrac{1-1/e}{n+1}
$.

Comment: Marty.Very nice

Answer (score 1):

By integrating multiple times the convexity inequality $e^{-x}\geq 1-x$ we have that $g(x)=\frac{1-x-e^{-x}}{x^2}$ is bounded between $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $-\frac{1}{e}$ over $(0,1)$. It follows that

$$ I(n)=\int_{0}^{1}x^n e^{-x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}x^n(1-x-x^2 g(x))\,dx =\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{C}{n+3},\quad C\in\left[\frac{1}{e},\frac{1}{2}\right].$$

We may also notice that
$$ (n+1) I(n) \stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=} \frac{1}{e}+I(n+1) $$
so by induction
$$ \int_{0}^{1}x^n e^{-x}\,dx = \frac{1}{e(n+1)}+\frac{1}{e(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{1}{e(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}+\ldots $$
where the RHS is obviously less than
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{e(n+1)^k} = \frac{1}{en}.$$

Answer (score 0):

An exact answer can be gotten
by using the fact
that this integral
is the lower
incomplete gamma function
$\gamma(n+1, 1)$.

Since 
$\gamma(s, x)
=\int_0^x t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt
=x^s\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-x)^k}{k!(s+k)}
$,
we have
$\gamma(n+1, 1)
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!(n+1+k)}
$.

Since the sum
is an alternating series
with decreasing terms,
its value is between
any two consecutive sums.

The first terms are
$\dfrac1{n+1},
-\dfrac1{1(n+2)},
\dfrac1{2(n+3)}
$,
so the sum is between
$\dfrac1{n+1}
-\dfrac1{(n+2)}
=\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
$
and
$\dfrac1{n+1}
-\dfrac1{1(n+2)}
+\dfrac1{2(n+3)}
=\dfrac{n^2 + 5 n + 8}{2 (n + 1) (n + 2) (n + 3)}\\
=\dfrac1{2n}-\dfrac{n^2 + 3 n + 6}{2 n (n + 1) (n + 2) (n + 3)}
$.

Another formula
which show the actual growth 
of the integral is

$\gamma(s, x)
=x^s e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^k}{s(s+1)...(s+k)}
$
so
$\gamma(n+1, 1)
= e^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+1+k)}\\
=\dfrac1{e(n+1)}+O(\dfrac1{n^2}).
$